# Prevent the file from deletion after apk uninstallation

Tags: java, android, download

```
Public static File getDirectory (String dir) 
{ 
    File file = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (dir); 
    if (! File.exists ()) 
    { 
        file.mkdirs (); 
    } Return file; 
}
```

i created a custom directory instead of a constant type. Example) /Custom/Data

And the download manager is request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(dir, fileName);

i understood Public Directory keep files when an app is deleted

Currently, when I check it with Galexy3, Vega, I checked that the data is retained even if the app is deleted. And api version of the test phone is kitkat (4.4.2).

but my main phone is on the gallexy 7 Edge. and api version is 7.0 in my phone, files deleted after app removed. even i using public directory and even if using constant type like Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i understood Public Directory keep files when an app is deleted

Not on newer versions of Android. See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=196821) and [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/02/09/changes-downloadmanager-behavior.html).

The only trick that I can think of to get around this would be to download the file to one location, then move it somewhere else.